# Initialize an Array Literal Without a Size

Tags: c, c89

I'm curious about the following expression:

```
int ints[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

This seems to compile fine even in c89 land with clang. Is there documentation about this? I can't seem to figure out the correct terminology to use when searching for it (and I'd rather not go through and read the entire c89 spec again).

Is this an extension? Is the compiler simply inferring the size of the array?

EDIT: I just remembered you guys like chunks of code that actually compile so here it is:

```
/* clang tst.c -o tst -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c89 */
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  int ints[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; 
  (void)(ints); (void)(argc); (void)(argv);
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: As you do not seem to be a lazy person, better go for reading the C11 specs.

Comment: @alk Apparently OP is asking whether this is valid strict C89. I'm pretty sure reading the C11 spec won't help.

Comment: This is not a "literal" but an "object".

Comment: @ace: "*... **even** in C89*": The OPs wording does not explicitly ask whether this is part of C89, no.

Comment: @alk Look at the [c89] tag and the sentence "This seems to compile fine even in c89 land with clang" that is what I would infer. Also after the edit the OP stated how this is compiled: `clang tst.c -o tst -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c89`

Comment: @ace: You are correct about this edit, indeed. However, as my comment obviously is coloured irconical reflecting on something else but the standard's version, I won't delete it.

Comment: @JensGustedt yes, apparently I'm pulling from other languages when I use the term "array literal", nonetheless it wouldn't be array object, would it? It should just be an object: "objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes"

Comment: @alk I'm currently bouncing around standards and not reading them from page 1 down. With this said I had not simply searched for the string `[]` like I probably should have, doh!

Comment: You are forgiven ... ;-) @DanZimm Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's part of standard C since [C89](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.5.7):

> #### §3.5.7 Initialization
>
> If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the number of initializers provided for its members. At the end of its initializer list, the array no longer has incomplete type.

In fact, there is an almost exact example:

> Example:
>
> The declaration
>
> ```
> int x[] = { 1, 3, 5 };
> ```
>
> defines and initializes `x` as a one-dimensional array object that has three members, as no size was specified and there are three initializers.

Comment: Upvoted and deleted mine, you're faster and better :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this an extension?

no, this is standard, for all versions of the C standard

by the `=` the array type is "incomplete" and then is completed by means of the initialization

> Is the compiler simply inferring the size of the
>   array?

yes

Comment: Thanks for the response - Yu was faster so I saw his first, sorry!